# Compass compiler Scout not compiling at all. Empty Log

Tags: configuration, sass, compass-sass, scout-sass

Scout won't even start. I've tried a bunch of different configurations (set the path to Config file). But nothing works. It's strange, I know that the project works with Scout on my work computer but not at home.
Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean it won't even start? If you can change the config, aren't you in the app already doing that?